# Break a one-line file to a multi-line file, each line with the same number of words?

Tags: bash, vim

E.g. One-line file `line.txt` has the following line:

`741 12 3 24 45 123 32 111 34`

Suppose specifying the number of words in each is `3`. then the goal is:

```
741 12 3
24 45 123
32 111 34
```

What scripts could help in this case, a simple one would be appreciated.

Comment: the number "3" is always given or should be calculated?

Comment: @Kent Good question. "3" is specified as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk '{ 
  for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) { 
    printf "%s%s", $i, (i % 3 == 0) ? "\n" : " " 
  } 
}' line.txt
```

It yields:

```
741 12 3
24 45 123
32 111 34
```

---

**EDIT** to fix the script (see comments) for a number of fields not multiple of 3:

```
awk '
  { 
    for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) { 
      printf "%s%s", $i, (i < NF && i % 3 == 0) ? "\n" : " " 
    } 
  } 
  END { printf "\n" }
' infile
```

Comment: If the number of words is not divisible by 3 (or whatever number the user specifies), the last line will end in a space but not a newline

Comment: Now it looks good.  Tiny nitpicky detail: the last line will have a trailing space, but that's probably okay in most cases

Answer (score 5):

this would be a easy job for awk. I saw the question with `vim` too, then tried it a bit with vim.

Assume that the cursor is at the beginning of the line. You could try to type (in `NORMAL` mode):

```
100@='3f r^M'
```

then type `Enter`.

The macro can be recorded by `qn3f r<Enter>q` too, then you just `100@n`

**Note**

- the `^M` you need to type `<C-V><Enter>`
- I didn't calculate how many times you should do the macro, so just gave 100. If the result would be more than 100 lines, you just give 500, or 1000. :)
- If the given number has problem, e.g. the line cannot be divided by 3, then the last line could contain columns less than the given number. e.g. 3.

Comment: Nice! The same answer for Emacs is definitely more convoluted: `C-x ( C-u 3 M-f C-d C-j C-x )` for defining the macro, and `C-x u 100 C-e` for running it 100 times.

Comment: @Thomas I don't know much about Emacs. I knew it is a greeeeeat editor. When I made my decision (abt 10 years ago), I just went to vim because with Emacs I need press `Ctrl` a lot, and the left Ctrl of that keyboard didn't work so well...so I took `Escape`. at that time I didn't think about swap keys... today my Caplock and Esc are swapped. anyway I am already with Vim and I am satisfied with it.  :)

Comment: @Thomas I forgot saying that I admire people who is good at `vim && emacs` :-) so `+1` your comment

Comment: Haha, that's a great story! :-) I don't really know how to use vim, but I wish I did. Some day when I have the time, I'll learn it.

Comment: ...and there's a typo in the Emacs version: to run the macro 100 times, type `C-x u 100 C-x e`.

Answer (score 2):

```
cat your_file | tr " " "\n" | paste -s -d "  \n"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
printf "%s %s %s\n" $(cat line.txt)
```

It yields

```
741 12 3
24 45 123
32 111 34
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using sed. With the number of words fixed to `3`, you could do:

```
sed 's/\( [^ ]* [^ ]*\) /\1\n/g' <filename>
```

If you want to dynamically specify the number of words, you can create the regexp on the fly with the following script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

test $# -eq 2 || (echo "Usage: $(basename "${0}") <filename> <#words>" && exit 1)

for i in $(seq 2 "${2}"); do
    REGEX=" [^ ]*${REGEX}"
done

cat "${1}" | sed "s/\\(${REGEX}\\) /\\1\n/g"
```

Comment: Which part is about the "3"?

Comment: It's the number of spaces in `sed`'s regular expression.